# Heroku: Cannot promote app from 'review' stage

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm producing an app in Heroku using Heroku Pipelines. I took over the project from someone else, so the current production app was created from a repository I'm not under control of. I pushed my new version of the app to the 'review' stage directly from Github. Now I want to promote my review app to the next stage in the pipeline: 'staging'.

I tried:

```
heroku pipelines:promote -r staging --app [nameofmyapp]
```

Heroku returned:

> Cannot promote [nameofmyapp] from 'review' stage

Any ideas as to why I am not allowed to promote my review app?

Answer (score 1):

Review apps cannot be promoted to the next stage.
They are created automatically when a Pull Request is opened, and deleted when it's closed or merged.

The way to promote that deployment to the next stage is to merge the pull request.